# Angular on ProfileImage Update also update header

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get achieve that the header user image which is the same one like the one on the profile page gets updated immediately when it gets changed.

When I insert a

```
ngDoCheck() {
    this.readProfileData();
}
```

it works but spams the server with 5 hibernate requests per second.
Profile and Header are two separat components.

```
readProfileData() {
this.userService.getProfile()
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(
    userData => {
      this.profileImage = userData.profileimage;
    });
if (this.profileImage != null) {
  this.hideDefaultImage = "true";
} else {
  this.hideDefaultImage = "false";
}
}
```

I use hideDefaultImage with the hidden option in html to look up if there is any picture or not and when there is not there's some default image. I know there is also *ngIf but had problems with it because it has always shown the default image for a short time.

So how can I achieve that when I update a new profile picture in my profile component that also the header get updated.

[image]

Comment: remove double quotes for both true and false;

Comment: That has nothing to do with my question. That was just an info. It needs to be a string value because HTML won't recognize boolean values there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a **Service**, inside the Service create an rxjs `Subject`

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';    

.....

profileImageUpdate$ = new Subject<string>();
```

In your profile component you should emit the url / base64 of the image whenever u change the profile image as follows:

```
this.userService.getProfile()
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(
    userData => {
      this.profileImage = userData.profileimage;
      this.userService.profileImageUpdate$.next(this.profileImage);
    });
```

In your header component, `subscribe` the subject in OnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.userService.profileImageUpdate$.subscribe((profileImage) => this.profileImage = profileImage);
}
```

*Don't forget to inject the service in both header and profile component*

Comment: What do you mean with create a service? Where to create one?

Comment: `ng g s myservice ` will create an angular service for you, which is a singleton class. google it you can learn how to creat it.

Comment: I know what a service is and how to create but I didn't get that you wanted me to create a new service. Couldn't I just do it in the userService?